# php UPDATE table row by row

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to update one table from another. I am SELECTing data from one table:

```
 $result2 = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM pages_language_overlay WHERE sys_language_uid = 1', $con);
```

And now I would like to update multiple tables row by row with selected data:

```
 while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

 $updatepowerfields = "UPDATE tx_powermail_fields SET tstamp='$row2[11]' WHERE    sys_language_uid = 0";
 mysql_query($updatepowerfields,$con);



 $updatepowerfieldsets = "UPDATE tx_powermail_fieldsets SET pid='$row2[0]',  tstamp='$row2[11]', crdate='$row2[12]', cruser_id='$row2[13]', 
 t3ver_oid='$row2[2]', t3ver_id='$row2[3]', t3ver_wsid='$row2[4]',    t3ver_label='$row2[5]', t3ver_state='$row2[6]', t3ver_stage='$row2[7]',    t3ver_count='$row2[8]', 
 t3ver_tstamp='$row2[9]', t3_origuid='$row2[10]', deleted='$row2[19]',   hidden='$row2[16]', starttime='$row2[17]', endtime='$row2[18]', title='$row2[15]'
                        WHERE sys_language_uid = 0";
 mysql_query($updatepowerfieldsets$con);            

 }
```

It works, but not how I was expecting. In first iteration of "while" it just rewrite whole table with one row. I need to update those tables row by row. What am I doing wrong? Can you please help me? Thank you

Comment: Run, you're gonna get yelled at by mysqli fans in a few seconds !

Comment: Your question needs more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    for($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($row2); i++) {
        mysql_query("update fld_name = $row2[i] where $id = '$i'");
    }
}
```

actually you don't need while loop as only one row is fetched!! Hope that helps.!!